# Unix / Linux file permissions change for group preserve for user / world

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

Is this possible? 
I have an issue granting a user access to website via FTP. The user can access them but cant delete or edit the files. I would like to change the permissions for the group so any user belonging to the group can edit those files but preserve (keep) the permissions for user / world.

Thanks in advance,
Joseph Mituzas

Comment: Sounds like a task for `chmod` then...

Comment: just don't know how to change just the group permissions on the files with chmod, so I don't mess up the permissions for the whole site. I can use the g= but from my understanding it will give the user and world no permission

Comment: Your understanding of `chmod` is incomplete. `g+r` would _add_ group read permissions while leaving everything else untouched.

Comment: Thank You !!!! So much for clearing that up, would hate to ess something up :)

Comment: Don't indicate `SOLVED` in the question title. That's what the tickmarks are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
chmod g+r filename
```

will merely *add* group read permissions to the file and not affect user or world permissions.  The command

```
chmod g=rw filename
```

will replace the current group permissions with read/write.

Neither of these commands will affect user and world permissions